# Expression Trees in Linq To Entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

I'm trying to make an extension method that takes in an expression that points to a property on an entity, and a constant string to compare it to using `String.Contains`, that first checks whether the string is null or empty, and applies the filter only if the string has a value. This is my first dabble in Expression Trees though, so I'm not really sure what's going on, and I now have an exception which I'm not sure how to cure...

I'm at this so far:

```vb
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function CheckAndFilter(Of T)(source As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of T), expressionField As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of T, String)), compareTo As String) As IQueryable(Of T)


        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(compareTo) Then
            Return source
        Else
            Dim memberExp As Expressions.MemberExpression = DirectCast(expressionField.Body, Expressions.MemberExpression)

            Dim param = Expressions.Expression.Parameter(GetType(T))
            Dim method As Reflection.MethodInfo = GetType(String).GetMethod("Contains")

            Dim compareToExpression = Expressions.Expression.Constant(compareTo)
            Dim finalExpr = Expressions.Expression.Call(memberExp, method, compareToExpression)

            Dim lambda = Expressions.Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))(finalExpr, param)
            Return source.Where(lambda)
        End If
    End Function
```

I'm calling it like this, against a `DbContext` where I have a `Customer` entity with a `FirstName` string property:

```vb
Dim results = repository.Customers.CheckAndFilter(Function(c) c.FirstName, searchText)
```

And the exception is:

```vb
{"The parameter 'c' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression."}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ha!

It's because I've declared a new parameter rather than re-using the one passed in via the expression...

```vb
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function CheckAndFilter(Of T)(source As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of T), expressionField As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of T, String)), compareTo As String) As IQueryable(Of T)


    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(compareTo) Then
        Return source
    Else
        Dim memberExp As Expressions.MemberExpression = DirectCast(expressionField.Body, Expressions.MemberExpression)

        Dim method As Reflection.MethodInfo = GetType(String).GetMethod("Contains")

        Dim compareToExpression = Expressions.Expression.Constant(compareTo)
        Dim finalExpr = Expressions.Expression.Call(memberExp, method, compareToExpression)

        Dim lambda = Expressions.Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))(finalExpr, expressionField.Parameters)
        Return source.Where(lambda)
    End If
End Function
```